# Vstudio 2022/Unity2021.3.3f1 CS0103 and CS0168

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a "souls-like" project to help me learn Unity/c#. I've found an excellent tutorial on youtube and followed it to a T. However upon trying to test the first bits of code out I'm running into many errors/warnings.

```
Error   CS0103  The name 'inputHandler' does not exist in the current context
```

This error is present for multiple variables that I named and used multiple times, but it can't figure out what they're referencing? I think? I'm a complete beginner at this and it's really frustrating me. I'm not sure if maybe the tutorial is outdated and the input control system in unity has updated to use different names for some of these pieces? At this point I don't even know if that makes sense lol. Here's the code for "playerLocomotion" script, the "InputHandler" script has no errors and seems fine.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace NN
{
    public class PlayerLocomotion : MonoBehaviour
    {

        void Start()
        {
            Transform cameraObject;
            InputHandler inputHandler;
            Vector3 moveDirection;
        }
        [HideInInspector]
        public Transform myTransform;

        public new Rigidbody rigidbody;
        public GameObject normalCamera;

        [Header("Stats")]
        [SerializeField]
        float movementSpeed = 5;
        [SerializeField]
        float rotationSpeed = 10;

        void start()
        {
            rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            inputHandler = GetComponent<InputHandler>();
            cameraObject = Camera.main.transform;
            myTransform = transform;

        }

        public void update()
        {
            float delta = Time.deltaTime;

            inputHandler.tickInput(delta);

            moveDirection = cameraObject.forward * inputHandler.vertical;
            moveDirection += cameraObject.right * inputHandler.horizontal;
            moveDirection.Normalize();

            float speed = movementspeed;
            moveDirection *= speed;

            Vector3 projectedVelocity = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(moveDirection, normalVector);
            rigidbody.velocity = projectedVelocity;
        }

        #region Movement

        Vector3 normalVector;
        Vector3 targetPosition;

        private void HandleRotation(float delta)
        {
            Vector3 targetDir = Vector3.zero;
            float moveOverride = inputHandler.moveAmount;

            targetDir = cameraObject.forward * inputHandler.vertical;
            targetDir = normalcamera.right * inputHandler.Horizontal;

            targetDir.Normalize();
            targetDir.y = 0;
            if (targetDir == Vector3.zero)
                targetDir = myTransform.forward;

            float rs = rotationspeed;

            Quaternion tr = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDir);
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, tr, rs * delta);

            myTransform.rotation = targetRotation;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: The variables defined in the Start method are not available anywhere else because of their scope. Try putting them outside the method. This tutorial explains scopes https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/variable-scopes-in-csharp

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much. I didn't even realize I placed them in there. Also thank you for the tutorial, definitely helped me understand it a bit better. Much appreciated friend.

Comment: Happy to help, feel free to accept the answer and good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables defined in the Start method are not available anywhere else because of their scope. Try putting them outside the method. This tutorial explains scopes in c# https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/variable-scopes-in-csharp

There where also some capitalization mishaps so i've also changed them in the example. I've added comments on the places where it throws an error.

I'd also like to add that it's good practice to define all your class level variables in the beginning of the class. That way you don't lose track of variables that are scattered across the class.

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace NN

{
    public class PlayerLocomotion : MonoBehaviour
    {
        
        //Putting these variables inside a method makes them method scoped variables, meaning that you can only access them inside this method
        //If you want to access them in the rest of the class they need to be defined in the class
        // void Start()
        // {
        //     Transform cameraObject;
        //     InputHandler inputHandler;
        //     Vector3 moveDirection;
        // }
        
        //This would be class level variables and these are now accessible in the rest of the class
        Transform cameraObject;
        InputHandler inputHandler;
        Vector3 moveDirection;
        
        [HideInInspector]
        public Transform myTransform;

        public new Rigidbody rigidbody;
        public GameObject normalCamera;

        [Header("Stats")]
        [SerializeField]
        float movementSpeed = 5;
        [SerializeField]
        float rotationSpeed = 10;

        void start()
        {
            rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            inputHandler = GetComponent<InputHandler>();
            cameraObject = Camera.main.transform;
            myTransform = transform;

        }

        public void update()
        {
            float delta = Time.deltaTime;

            inputHandler.tickInput(delta);

            moveDirection = cameraObject.forward * inputHandler.vertical;
            moveDirection += cameraObject.right * inputHandler.horizontal;
            moveDirection.Normalize();

            // float speed = movementspeed; //This also contained a capitalization error
            float speed = movementSpeed; //Should be movementSpeed instead of movementspeed
            
            moveDirection *= speed;

            Vector3 projectedVelocity = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(moveDirection, normalVector);
            rigidbody.velocity = projectedVelocity;
        }

        #region Movement

        Vector3 normalVector;
        Vector3 targetPosition;

        private void HandleRotation(float delta)
        {
            Vector3 targetDir = Vector3.zero;
            float moveOverride = inputHandler.moveAmount;

            targetDir = cameraObject.forward * inputHandler.vertical;
            // targetDir = normalcamera.right * inputHandler.Horizontal; //should also be normalCamera instead of normalcamera
            //The normalcamera is also a gameobject so it doesn't have a right, so you'll first have to get the transform
            targetDir = normalCamera.transform.right * inputHandler.Horizontal;
            
            targetDir.Normalize();
            targetDir.y = 0;
            if (targetDir == Vector3.zero)
                targetDir = myTransform.forward;

            // float rs = rotationspeed;//This should also be rotationSpeed instead of rotationspeed
            float rs = rotationSpeed;

            Quaternion tr = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDir);
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, tr, rs * delta);

            myTransform.rotation = targetRotation;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```